# How to perform List View sort from code?

Tags: c#, listview, sorting

I'm looking for instruction to sort my `listView` after adding items. I don't want to use "auto sorting" because its very, very slow. I have 5 columns but I want to sort only by first column. Anyone?

```
 listView1.BeginUpdate();
 while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
 listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { csv[0], csv[1], csv[2], csv[3], csv[4] }));
 // sort here
 listView1.EndUpdate();
 // or here
```

Comment: "I don't want to use "auto sorting" because its very very slow" - perhaps you have too many items?  ? ?

Comment: Did you try to just call `listView1.Items.Sort()` after the while Loop (with auto sorting disabled)? If this is not faster, the performance penalty is not in the auto sorting, but in the number of elements.

Comment: Yes its slow when i have 50k-1mln items in listView. 

@PMF
I cant call listView1.Items.Sort(). Only listView.Sort() but its not working.

Comment: Wait... You have 50k to 1 Million elements in the listview? Then I don't wonder. Those controls are not really designed for that. I think you should keep your list separated (in a List<T>) and just show the currently visible elements, implementing the scrollbar functionality yourself.

Comment: Yes its csv viewer/editor for classes. I have to use listView and sort it only once after loading csv file.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here is store you're data in a generic list and sort it before showing on the ui. Controls don't typically work well with that amount of data and therefore you have the added advantage of controlling a vie of your original data.

The other thing you can do here is provide a custom sorter to the list.sort method. Typically however your unlikely to get huge savings over the framework. Consider are sorting and displaying a progress indicator while waiting instead, this is pretty typical for long running processes.

If you want to do custom during look at the following link about custom compares [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)